# Program that will create an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I am having trouble starting out this program, I am suppose to write a program that will create an ArrayList, asking the user for 10 numbers. Then this will be put into the Array. Then after the list is made navigate it and if a number is even remove it from the ArrayList and copy it to a stack of integers.

```
import java.io.* ;
import java.util.*;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args){


    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

    ArrayList<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    System.out.print ("Enter Number: \n");

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        integers.add(input.nextInt());
        }

    for (int i= 0; i < 10 ; i++){
       int item = myListIterator.getNext();
        if(item % 2 == 0)
            {
                myListIterator.remove(); //removes it from the ArrayList
                myStack.push(item); //puts it into the stack
            }
  }
  Stack<Integer> st1;
  st1 = new Stack <Integer> ();



}
}
```

Comment: what do you have so far...also sounds like homework, if so please tag it homework

Comment: What part are you having trouble with?

Comment: well right now I don't have anything. I don't know if I need to classes for this or what. I am quite confused

Comment: Definitely agree with @hvgotcodes - let's see what you have so far. Also, do you have to define your own stack class or can you use java.util.Stack?

Comment: I would advocate using java.util.Deque over the legacy Stack class.

Comment: import java.io.* ;
import java.util.*;

public class ArrayList {

 public static void main(String[] args){

  Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

  ArrayList<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

  int[] numbers = {System.in};
          for (int item : numbers) {
            System.out.println("Count is: " + item);


 }
}

}

Comment: @helloman: put your code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the official [Lesson: The "Hello World!" Application](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/index.html) to get started with a basic program.

Then I suggest you use a `Scanner` to read user input. You could initialize it like this

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
```

and then read numbers from the user, using the `Scanner.nextInt` method. (Have a look at the [official tutorial on The for Statement](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) and you'll probably figure out how to do this ten times.)

Create the ArrayList like this

```
ArrayList<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

and put the provided numbers in the `ArrayList` using the `add` method.

Then I'd suggest you use an `Iterator<Integer>` (which you can get hold of from `integers.iterator()`, and loop while `iterator.hasNext()` and if `iterator.next()` is an even number, you do `iterator.remove()`.

---

```
int[] numbers = {System.in};
for (int item : numbers) {
    System.out.println("Count is: " + item);
```

doesn't look too good.

Try something like

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    integers.add(input.nextInt());
```

Comment: it says im not setting my parameters for ArrayList

Comment: Don't name your class `ArrayList`. That is kind of taken... rename your class to `Assignment` or something.

Comment: @aioobe ideally his professor didn't make him name it that way

Comment: now how do I remove the even numbers and put them into a stack

Answer (score 0):

Well so far you have the input from the user. Now you need to do the following:

1. Check if the `current` value is `even`, this is a `modulus` operation
2. In the event that `current` is `even`, `push current` onto a `Stack` and `pop` it from your `ArrayList`
3. Change the name of your homework assignment to something that is not `ArrayList` unless that is what your professor asked
4. To validate the `Stack` only has `even` values, you may decide to `pop` everything off and print that information

Comment: Right, now what about the if statement for the modulus operation...How would i remove that even number and put it into a stack?

Answer (score 0):

You already have most of the code in place.  You just need to add them to a stack.  The java Stack class can be found here:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html

So constructing the ArrayList you just have to find even integers, remove them, and add it to the stack.  Note that

```
if (i %2==0)
```

is incorrect, because we're not concerned about "i" being even, we're concerned about integers.get(i) being even.  To loop through your ArrayList, you should use an Iterator.  Using a manual index to find the even integers, while possible, is very prone to error (because you are constantly changing the size of the ArrayList!)  Help can be found here:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html

So you would have

```
int item = myListIterator.getNext();
if(item % 2 == 0)
{
    myListIterator.remove(); //removes it from the ArrayList
    myStack.push(item); //puts it into the stack
}
```

in your loop.  The initialization of the Stack is pretty trivial and if this is a homework assignment, you should know how to do that so I will leave you to figure it out.

Comment: the stack where should i put it tho? do i need to make a new class, sorry just really confused

Comment: Stack is already a java class.  You just need to say something like "Stack<Integer> myStack = new Stack<Integer>()".  It's just like an ArrayList.